# Accessing Service Bus 1.1 from windows Service

Tags: windows-services, servicebus

I have set up a **Service bus 1.1 for windows server** and trying to access it using the following code.

```
    var sbUriList = new List<Uri>() { new UriBuilder { Scheme = "sb", Host = ServerFQDN, Path = ServiceNamespace }.Uri };
    var httpsUriList = new List<Uri>() { new UriBuilder { Scheme = "https", Host = ServerFQDN, Path = ServiceNamespace, Port = HttpPort }.Uri };

    NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential("<User Name>", "<Password>", "<Domain>");

    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback((s, cert, chain, ssl) => { return true; });

    TokenProvider tokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateOAuthTokenProvider(httpsUriList, credential);
    messageFactory = MessagingFactory.Create(sbUriList, tokenProvider);



    ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder connBuilder = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder();
    connBuilder.ManagementPort = HttpPort;
    connBuilder.RuntimePort = TcpPort;
    connBuilder.Endpoints.Add(new UriBuilder() { Scheme = "sb", Host = ServerFQDN, Path = ServiceNamespace }.Uri);
    connBuilder.StsEndpoints.Add(new UriBuilder() { Scheme = "https", Host = ServerFQDN, Port = HttpPort, Path = ServiceNamespace }.Uri);

    namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connBuilder.ToString());

if (!namespaceManager.QueueExists(queuename))
{
    namespaceManager.CreateQueue(queuename);
}
```

this works fine if i run my code from a console application, but however if I put this in a **windows service** and run it under either a **Local service** or **Local System** the code throws the following exception while trying to check if the queue exists in the following line `namespaceManager.QueueExists(queuename)`.

```
Unexpected exception : System.UnauthorizedAccessException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. Manage claim is required for this operation..TrackingId:5be1365e-b4ae-4555-b81b-dcbef96be9d0_GIE11LT32PD622,TimeStamp:4/19/2015 3:51:28 PM ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ServiceBusResourceOperations.GetAsyncResult`1.<GetAsyncSteps>b__2d(GetAsyncResult`1 thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: please delete your question - which was A bug in your own code...

Comment: @Sreeram: I could delete it, but it took me almost 2 days to figure out how to make it working. There was almost no resource on the internet that tells you how to do this. So thought I would leave it here in case some one else has a similar issue.

Comment: @Kiran, I don't think that this a valid reason to delete a question. You should remove your downvote. FYI: I found this post helpful. This isn't so much a bug, but rather the lack of a thorough walkthru available from microsoft. I could not find this answer anywhere else!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the issue in my code, thought i'll share it in case anyone else has the same issue.

my issue was that in the namespace I had not set the token as below:

`namespaceManager.Settings.TokenProvider = tokenProvider;`

as a result of which it was using the wrong token for connection and hence the error.